# Asp.Net 5 DI Singleton for expensive object a good idea?

Tags: performance, caching, serialization, asp.net-core

Suppose I have an object such as a tree of site navigation nodes that may be expensive to build from scratch and when it gets large it may grow expensive to deserialize from cache.

Suppose I register my ITreebuilder as a singleton in DI

```
services.TryAdd(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<INavigationTreeBuilder, XmlNavigationTreeBuilder>());
```

and consumers call its GetTree method shown below:

```
private TreeNode<NavigationNode> rootNode = null;

public async Task<TreeNode<NavigationNode>> GetTree()
{
    if (rootNode == null)
    {
        await cache.ConnectAsync();
        byte[] bytes = await cache.GetAsync(cacheKey);
        if (bytes != null)
        {
            string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            rootNode = BuildTreeFromJson(json);
        }
        else
        {
            rootNode = await BuildTree();
            string json = rootNode.ToJsonCompact();

            await cache.SetAsync(
                            cacheKey,
                            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json),
                            new DistributedCacheEntryOptions().SetSlidingExpiration(
                                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100))
                                );
        }
    }

    return rootNode;
}
```

This singleton object will be kept in memory for the life of the application right?
Each web server node would have it's own copy of this singleton but after the first node put the object in the distributed cache the other nodes would not have to build it?
The missing piece would be how to detect when the distributed cache is invalidated so the internal rootNode could be rebuilt when needed

Does this sound like a good or reasonable or feasible strategy to manage a potentially expensive object like this?

It avoids the deserialization expense that would be involved if we get the tree from the distributed cache on every web request. I thought about using IMemoryCache to store the object after deserializing it to avoid deserializing it on each web request, but this idea seems like it would keep it in memory without me having to manage 2 layers of caching and be easier to implement.

Any tips on how to detect when the distributed cache has been invalidated or updated without requesting the object from the cache? Maybe I could cache a smaller object at the same time with a timestamp and I could just check if this timestamp changed?

Comment: I guess I would also need to add locking since it would be a singleton right?

Comment: Can you define "expensive"? Did you profile the code to see how expensive is the creation of that object? Just trying to see if it makes sense to look into complex solutions before you actually have numbers...

Comment: as mentioned it will be a tree of navigation nodes for a web site. Some nodes of the tree will be built from an xml file or json file but a node can provide the name of another node builder that can be invoked to build sub trees onto the main tree. A cms for example will add nodes from the database. The number of pages in a site can grow very large even if the average site will not be that large, I need to build for the large site scenario. I guess it is a similar problem to solve as the old sitemap in webforms. The tree will be used to build navigation menus and breadcrumbs.